# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework' (tried many solutions but not working)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have encountered this error.

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'`

I have a virtual environment setted up and the rest framework is installed correctly.

When I run `pip3.10 show djangoframework`, I get

```
Name: djangorestframework
Version: 3.14.0
Summary: Web APIs for Django, made easy.
Home-page: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/
Author: Tom Christie
Author-email: tom@tomchristie.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\chan\desktop\testpy\lib\site-packages
Requires: django, pytz
Required-by:
```

My interpreter is Python 3.10.8 which is the same version and it is for the virtual environment. my VSCode shows my interpreter as `Python 3.10.8 ("TESTPY":venv) .\Scripts\python.exe`.

I also have included the rest_framework in the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Below is the full error I get.

```
(TESTPY) PS C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\TESTPY> python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception 
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute     
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

I have googled to fix this issue so many times now that all the links are purple.. Anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Edit:

When I run `pip list`, this is what I get.

```
(TESTPY) PS C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\TESTPY> pip list
Package             Version
------------------- -------
asgiref             3.5.2
Django              4.1.2
djangorestframework 3.14.0
pip                 22.3
pytz                2022.5
setuptools          63.2.0
sqlparse            0.4.3
tzdata              2022.5
```

Comment: Make sure the virtual environment you run the code has `djangorestframework`. You can do pip list to check the installed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use just the `python` command instead of `python3`.

When you activate a virtualenv, what happens is that some shell binaries are added to your `PATH`. These binaries are typically `python` and `pip`, and maybe other binaries from other pip packages that are installed in the virtualenv.

So then when the virtualenv is activated, the `python` command will execute the python binary inside the virtualenv. But the `python3` executable is not overriden, so when you execute that, you just get your system `python3`.

So try:

```bash
python manage.py runserver
```

Or maybe you could even just do:

```bash
./manage.py runserver
```

If that doesn't work, it might be because the `manage.py` file needs to have [execute permissions](https://linuxhandbook.com/chmod-command/):

```bash
chmod +x manage.py
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I don't get it! the python in my virtual environment is also python version 3.10, but why is python3 not overriden?

Comment: @brady I updated the answer with more explanation. Is it clear like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two different python installations

from `pip3 show`, there is this line:

```
Location: c:\users\chan\desktop\testpy\lib\site-packages
```

but your stack trace is listing files that are in

```
File "C:\Users\Chan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\
```

Comment: Yes, it was because I was calling global python by using python3... somehow python3 is not overriden when python is.